# Ubuntu autoinstall not honoring source: id: "ubuntu-server-minimized"

Tags: 22.04, autoinstall

The documentation at https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference states:

```
source
[search_drivers stuff omitted]
  id
    type: string
    default: identifier of the first available source.
```

Identifier of the source to install (e.g., "ubuntu-server-minimized").
However, this doesn't work

```
source:
  id: "ubuntu-server-minimized"
```

in cloud-config user-data leads to an error.
I've tried with `"`, `'` and without quotes, but autoinstall fails.

`/var/crash/blah.meta states`:

```
{
  "kind": "UNKNOWN"
}
```

And what is meant by "Identifier of the source to install" anyway?
Please update the doc here to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: Can you try an `id` of `ubuntu-server-minimal`?  Based on https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/automated-server-installer-config-file-reference/16613/46

Comment: This does actually work, marvelous